# SolverStudio how to reference 1 column in a 2D list in a for loop(PuLP)

Tags: excel, solver, pulp

I have 2 data sets x1 and x2. I want to be able to get a total sum of all the products of x1 and x2 only in the rows where the From column has Auckland in it.
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb9Q4.png)

The final answer should be (5*1) + (2*1) + (3*1) + (4*1) or 14. The PuLP code that I wrote to do this is given below

```
# Import PuLP modeller functions
from pulp import *

varFinal = sum([x1[a] * x2[a] for a in Arcs if a == Nodes[0]])

print Nodes[0]
print Arcs[0]

Final = varFinal
```

The output that gets printed to the console is

> Auckland
>  
>   ('Auckland', 'Albany')

I realise that my final value is zero because Arcs[some number] does not equal Nodes[some number]. Is there anyway to change the code so my final value is 14?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow! Cause you've only posted part of your code, I have to guess at what data-types you're using. From the output, I'm guessing your `Nodes` are strings, and your `Arcs` are tuples of strings.

Your attempt is very close, you want the from column to have Auckland in it. You can index into a tuple the same way you would into an array, so you want to do: `a[0] == Nodes[0]`.

Below is a self-contained example with the first bit of your data in which outputs the following (note that I've changed to python 3.x print statements (with parentheses)):

Output:

```
Auckland
('Auckland', 'Albany')
14
```

Code:

```
# Import PuLP modeller functions
from pulp import *

# Data
Nodes = ['Auckland',
        'Wellington',
        'Hamilton',
        'Kansas City',
        'Christchuch',
        'Albany',
        'Whangarei',
        'Rotorua',
        'New Plymouth']

Arcs = [('Auckland','Albany'),
        ('Auckland','Hamilton'),
        ('Auckland','Kansas City'),
        ('Auckland','Christchuch'),
        ('Wellington','Hamilton'),
        ('Hamilton','Albany'),
        ('Kansas City','Whangarei'),
        ('Christchuch','Rotorua')]

x1_vals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 11, 13]
x2_vals = [5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

x1 = dict((Arcs[i], x1_vals[i]) for i in range(len(Arcs)))
x2 = dict((Arcs[i], x2_vals[i]) for i in range(len(Arcs)))

varFinal = sum([x1[a] * x2[a] for a in Arcs if a[0] == Nodes[0]])

print(Nodes[0])
print(Arcs[0])
print(varFinal)
```

For future reference, answers are most likely to be forthcoming if you include code which others can try to run (without external data dependencies), that way people can try to run it, fix it, and re-post it.

Comment: Hi kabdulla, thanks a lot for your help. I was wondering if x1 and x2 was to now have an index range equal to Arcs set by the Data Items Editor, How would you alter the above code to make it work?
See below
https://i.imgur.com/3pRHm4X.png
https://i.imgur.com/6imfPDm.png

Comment: I've never used solver studio and don't know what data items editor is. Also those images are very pixelated. Perhaps you could edit your question with an embedded image and someone might be able to help.